# Laravel 5: Why am I able to retrieve data in json format but the data is unavailable in my view?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm currently working with Laravel 5.4 and it's my first time working with laravel. I have created some post with tags attached and attempting to retrieve all post for specific tags. With my code, no error is returned but no post is returned for that tag as well (strange because the page renders without an error). I tried returning just the $post result from the query and I'm able to get the post in JSON style. I need help figuring out what i'm doing wrong to cause this strange occurrence.

[image]

PostController for Route::get('/category/{category}', 'PostController@category');

```
public function category($category)
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($category) {

        //dd($category);

        $query->where('name', '=', $category);

    })->get();

    $archives = Post::archives();

    return view('post.category', compact('posts', 'category', 'archives'));
    //return $posts;
}
```

Post model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

Tag model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

post.category

```
@if (count($posts) > 0)

        @foreach ($posts as $post)

            <div class="row panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                    <h3>{{ $post->caption }}</h3>

                    <p class="note">{{ $post->note }} &nbsp; <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}">Read more...</a></p>

                </div>

            </div>
        @endforeach

    @else

        <h4>There are no post yet for this category</h4>

    @endif
```

Comment: for testing try to add `<pre> {{ $posts }} <pre>` in the view or trace the request in the dev tool and send us the posts returned

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. Code has been edited to show working code

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. The error was because of a line i was playing with in the view {{ $post->tags()->pluck('name') }}. Delete or comment out that line and that fixed it.